# Template Code for Newsletter Text next to image - Compatibility Issues with some email clients

Tags: html, css, html-email, mailchimp, newsletter

I am trying to create a email template for sending rss posts through mailchimp once a week.
I am experiencing a problem but not on all email clients.
I need to show text next to the image (on PC) and text under an image (on smaller devices), my code does just that, but for some reason on thunderbird it displays wrongly.

I Edited the code, to show the working one.

```
  <div class="mcnTextContent">
    <style type="text/css">
      .testsitenewsletterimage11 p {
        float: left !important;
      }
      .testsitenewslettertxt11 p {
        display: inline-block!important;
        padding-left: 20px;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .testsitenewslettertxt11 hr {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
         .endfeedrss {
        display: block!important;
               clear: both;

      }
        .testsitenewsletterstart {
        display: block!important;
      }

      .im {
        color: #757575 !important;
      }

    </style>

   <div class="testsitenewsletterstart">
       *|FEEDBLOCK:http://testsite.edu.gr/category/%CE%B5%CE%BA%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1-%CE%BD%CE%B5%CE%B1/feed/|*
    *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=3]|*
    <div class="testsitenewsletterimage11">

      <p><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*">*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*</a></p>
      <div class="testsitenewslettertxt11">
        <p>
          <span style="font-size:14px">*|FEEDITEM:DATE|*</span><br />
          <strong>*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|* </strong><br />
          <a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*"> &Mu;ά&theta;&epsilon;&tau;&epsilon;
            &Pi;&epsilon;&rho;&iota;&sigma;&sigma;ό&tau;&epsilon;&rho;&alpha;</a>
            <br />
        </p>


      </div>

    </div>
          <span class="endfeedrss"> 
          <hr /> <br />
    *|END:FEEDITEMS|* *|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
       </span>
      </div>


  </div>
```

- What i want to achieve on PC: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp4EX.jpg
- Problem on thunderbird (on PC): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCL4K.jpg

can anyone let me know how to fix the problem on thunderbird? I am not able to debug as I dont know how to check the thunderbird email code like in firefox "Element Inspector"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. I don't have an option to test it in the Thunderbird.
I changed the order  for *br* tag and his class.

```
    <div class="mcnTextContent">
      <style type="text/css">
        .testsitenewsletterimage11 p {
          float: left !important;
        }
        .testsitenewslettertxt11 p {
          display: inline !important;
          padding-left: 20px;
          width: 50%;
        }
        .testsitenewslettertxt11 hr {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .im {
          color: #757575 !important;
        }
      </style>

      *|FEEDBLOCK:http://testsite.edu.gr/category/%CE%B5%CE%BA%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1-%CE%BD%CE%B5%CE%B1/feed/|*
      *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=3]|*
      <div class="testsitenewsletterimage11">
        <p><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*">*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*</a></p>
        <div class="testsitenewslettertxt11">
          <p>
            <span style="font-size:14px">*|FEEDITEM:DATE|*</span><br />
            <strong>*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|* </strong><br />
            <a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*"> &Mu;ά&theta;&epsilon;&tau;&epsilon;
              &Pi;&epsilon;&rho;&iota;&sigma;&sigma;ό&tau;&epsilon;&rho;&alpha;</a
            ><br />
          </p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
      *|END:FEEDITEMS|* *|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does the same thing on Thunderbird.    See the screenshot  https://imgur.com/XRpiy7L

Comment: The problem solved by setting a new span class "endfeedrss" and adding "clear: both;" to it.

Comment: This method will not work properly in Outlook. Outlook reads div as block elements only.